# Oracle XE and DBMS_CRYPTO

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe, dbms-crypto

is there no DBMS_CRYPTO package on Oracle XE databases?
I searched the SYS user packages and all I could find was a DBMS_CRYPTO_TOOLKIT

When I try to grant execute on DBMS_CRYPTO I get an error that the Table or View was not found. 
Is it stored anywhere else?

I hope you can help me :) THX

Comment: I don't use it, but I don't see anything [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC115) saying it shouldn't be there. Maybe a silly question, but are you logged in as SYS when you look for it; or are you looking in `all_objects` as another user, who wouldn't see it listed if they didn't already have execute privileges on it?

Comment: Thx for your answer. I am logged in with the SYSTEM user but look at the SYS packages. I think it is not possible to log in with the SYS user.

Comment: Unless you have access to a user who already has that privilege with the grant option, you (or your DBA) will need to grant it from the SYS account. (Assuming it exists of course).

Comment: Thx. I managed to login with sys privileges. Now I can see dbs crypto

Answer (score 2):

DBMS_CRYPTO exists! I had to log in with the SYS user to see the package.